# Oracle difference between Global and Local indexes in Partitioned tables

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

Right now, I only understand that Global indexes on a partitioned table are for the whole table where as the local indexes are for each partition.

If so, Is the Primary Key also a Global Index?

What happens to the Indexes when a Partition is moved to some other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the primary key is a global index.

If some table data was moved to another partition, any indexes pointing to that data would be updated accordingly.  (Is that what you meant with your last question?)

Comment: Thanks for the doubt to be cleared on the Primary index and a Global Index..
Whereas the other Question what i ment was.. what happens to the global as well as local indexes created on the Table whose Partion has been moved to some other table.. where there may or may not be any Index..

Comment: Am I right about the Idea I have on Local and Global indexes..?